# ¿Cómo puedo mandar un mail con archivo .PDF usando MimeKit en C#?

Tags: c#, email, mime

Estoy tratando de mandar un mail con el MimeKit de la siguiente manera:

```
   private bool EnviarMail(string file, string from, string to, string subject, string contenido, string nombre)
    {
        bool estado = false;

        try
        {
            var mensaje = new MimeMessage();
            mensaje.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(nombre, from));
            mensaje.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", to));
            mensaje.Subject = subject;

            //var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
            //bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = contenido;
            //bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(file);

            //mensaje.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

            var body = new TextPart()
            {
                Text = contenido
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient("Host", puerto))
            {
                client.Send(mensaje);    
            }

            estado = true;
            return estado;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return estado;
        }
    }
```

Pero tengo el siguiente error en `client.Send(mensaje);`

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MimeKit.MimeMessage' to ' System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'

Entiendo lo que me dice el error pero no sé cómo cambiar el código para que funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui hay dos problemas

- TEMA 1: Adjuntar un archivo PDF en [MimeMessage](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeMessage.htm)
- TEMA 2: Error en Send de SmtpClient

**TEMA 1: Adjuntar un archivo PDF en [MimeMessage](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeMessage.htm)**

Para poder armar un email con [MimeMessage]
(http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeMessage.htm) te tienes que ayudar con la método Add de la colección de adjuntos [BodyBuilder.Attachments](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MimeKit_BodyBuilder_Attachments.htm) , que tiene 7 sobrecargas (puedes pasar el byte[], stream, etc)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al final deberias utilizar el método [BodyBuilder.ToMessageBody()](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_BodyBuilder_ToMessageBody.htm) para armar el body

```
email.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
```

que lo que hace textual de la ayuda

> Construye el cuerpo (body) del mensaje basándose en los cuerpos basados en texto (text-based), los recursos vinculados y los archivos adjuntos.

Ejemplo en tu código, obteniendo "fisicamente" el archivo PDF (pero puede venir de la DB, API, storage, etc)

```
var mensaje = new MimeMessage();
mensaje.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(nombre, from));
mensaje.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", to));
mensaje.Subject = subject;

var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();


//mensaje.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

//Adjuntar PDF
//Paso 1: Obtenter archivo (path, db, etc), se necesita un byte[]
var pdfFilePath = @"path_archivo_PDF.pdf";   
var pdfByte = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);

//Adjuntarlo con bodyBuilder
bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(fileName: "Archivo_1.pdf",
                            data: pdfByte,
                            contentType: MimeKit.ContentType.Parse(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf));
                            
                            
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = contenido;

email.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
```

**TEMA 2: Error en Send de SmtpClient**

Con respecto al envio con SmtpClient que obtienes el error, es porque tienes que utilizar [MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient.htm) que es lo que recomienda Microsoft de utilizar en vez de [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Importante: No se recomienda usar la SmtpClient clase para el nuevo desarrollo porque SmtpClient no admite muchos protocolos modernos. En su lugar, use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) u otras bibliotecas. Para obtener más información, [consulte SmtpClient no se debe usar en GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md).

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [BodyBuilder.Attachments Property](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MimeKit_BodyBuilder_Attachments.htm)
- [BodyBuilder.ToMessageBody()](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_BodyBuilder_ToMessageBody.htm)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Answer (score 1):

Por que no lo intentas con MailMessage. te dejo un codigo que deberia funcionar.

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("enviar_a@gmail.com");
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("Enviar_de@gmail.com", "PRUEBA");

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "TITULO";
message.Body = "CUERPO DEL CORREO";

message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(GetStreamFile("RUTA_DEL_ARCHIVO.PDF"), Path.GetFileName("RUTA_DEL_ARCHIVO.PDF"), "application/pdf"));

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Enviar_de@gmail.com", "contraseñacorreo"),
    EnableSsl = true
};

try
{
    client.Send(message);
    Console.Writeln("Correo enviado");
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    Console.Writeln("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```